# Removing intermediate table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following tables:

```
Table1
| id | intermediate_id |

Itermediate
| id |

Table2
| id | intermediate_id | table1_id|
```

**How do i update Table2 with Table1.ids?**

I'm trying the following:

```
update Table2
set table1_id = 
(select table1.id 
 from table1
 where table1.intermediate_id = table2.intermediate_id);
```

which gives me "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: Your error is stating that one `intermediate_id` exists on more than one row in `table1`. In such a case, you're trying to push more than one `table1.id` value into a single `table2.table1_id` field. Try ***`SELECT intermediate_id, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 GROUP BY intermediate_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`*** to find such occurances.

Comment: Should the intermediate table allow a many:many relationship? *(Is your data correct?)* Or are you ***certain*** that each row in table2 should only ever relate to one row in table1? *(Is your data incorrect?)*

Comment: Yes, you're right it is many to many relationship. And i'm trying to make it one to one. Thank you.

Comment: Then you need to modify the data to actually be 1:1 *(or 1:many, which your new relationship will currently allow)* before you run your update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Table2
set table1_id = table1.id
  from table1
  where table1.intermediate_id = table2.intermediate_id
```

Comment: ok, i accept this to close the question, but the problem was in actual relationship between tables.